# MSACCESS SQL Error 3021 - Updates Locally but not to Server

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an already existing form that I added one new textbox to that allows the user to input notes. I have 2 queries that run when the submission button is clicked, one to update a local table within MSACCESS and the other is on our server. The new button is called DISPATCH_NOTES, it is also the name of the column in the tables.

BEFORE (Working)
LOCAL:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE WCL_DATABASE_QUERY " & vbNewLine & _
         "SET WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.COMMENTS ='" & Me.COMMENTS.Value & "',WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.DISPATCH_NOTES ='" & Me.DISPATCH_NOTES.Value & "', WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST ='" & GetUsername & "', WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE = " & PSD & "WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.LAST_UPDATE =#" & Now() & "#" & vbNewLine & _
         "WHERE (((WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID) in ('" & Join(POList, "', '") & "'))) AND ORDER_STATUS = 'OPEN';"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Before (Working) SERVER:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE TrafficDatabase_Query " & vbNewLine & _
             "SET TrafficDatabase_Query.COMMENTS ='" & Me.COMMENTS.Value & "', TrafficDatabase_Query.DISPATCH_NOTES ='" & Me.DISPATCH_NOTES.Value & "', TrafficDatabase_Query.TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST ='" & GetUsername & "', TrafficDatabase_Query.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE = " & PSD & "TrafficDatabase_Query.LAST_UPDATE =#" & Now() & "#" & vbNewLine & _
             "WHERE (((LTRIM(RTRIM(TrafficDatabase_Query.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID)) & TrafficDatabase_Query.DELIVERY_NUMBER) in (" & PODO & ")));"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

After (Working) LOCAL:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE WCL_DATABASE_QUERY " & vbNewLine & _
             "SET WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.COMMENTS ='" & Me.COMMENTS.Value & "',WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.DISPATCH_NOTES ='" & Me.DISPATCH_NOTES.Value & "', WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST ='" & GetUsername & "', WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE = " & PSD & "WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.LAST_UPDATE =#" & Now() & "#" & vbNewLine & _
             "WHERE (((WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID) in ('" & Join(POList, "', '") & "'))) AND ORDER_STATUS = 'OPEN';"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

After (Broken) SERVER:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE TrafficDatabase_Query " & vbNewLine & _
             "SET TrafficDatabase_Query.COMMENTS ='" & Me.COMMENTS.Value & "', TrafficDatabase_Query.DISPATCH_NOTES ='" & Me.DISPATCH_NOTES.Value & "', TrafficDatabase_Query.TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST ='" & GetUsername & "', TrafficDatabase_Query.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE = " & PSD & "TrafficDatabase_Query.LAST_UPDATE =#" & Now() & "#" & vbNewLine & _
             "WHERE (((LTRIM(RTRIM(TrafficDatabase_Query.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID)) & TrafficDatabase_Query.DELIVERY_NUMBER) in (" & PODO & ")));"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

[image]

This is the Debug.Print strSQL before the LOCAL:

```
UPDATE WCL_DATABASE_QUERY 
SET WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.COMMENTS ='Sent to Dispatch',WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.DISPATCH_NOTES ='Please ship these PO's 1st, they have been coded WCLA.', WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST ='JRussi', WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE = Null, WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.LAST_UPDATE =#10/19/2021 1:41:57 PM#
WHERE (((WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID) in ('6596145'))) AND ORDER_STATUS = 'OPEN';
```

Comment: are you getting any error messages? whats your error handling look like?

Comment: I added the pop up when I run it.

Comment: Please show us what you get from `Debug.Print strSQL` for the broken update statement.

Comment: I was just handed this task, not too familiar with VBA. Where do I put that in the VBA?

Comment: Insert a line before `CurrentDb.Execute` and put `Debug.Print strSQL` there.  Then after you run the code, you can view the output in the Immediate window; CTRL+g will take you there.

Comment: in the immediate section, it just returns blank.

Comment: Okay the local is not working now. I will attach in the main post.

Comment: WOW, thank you for that help! The issue was the comment had an ' in it breaking up the SQL.

Comment: Consider switching to a [parameter query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed) to avoid problems with apostrophes within strings.

Comment: I believe you need to use the `dbSeeChanges` flag when updating on a server. In your case that would be `dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges`.